# react-native does not support RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

I have this one line of code:

```
console.log("this is an example of test".match(new RegExp('.{0,3}am.{0,3}','gi')));
```

If I paste this into chrome developer tools for the console, I get this:

```
[" example"]
```

But when I run this same line of code in react-native, I get this

```
[ 'this is an example of test' ]
```

How do I get the react-native version of regex to give me the output `[" example"]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the regular expression engine in react native.

As a workaround, you can use `(.{0,3})am.{0,3}` which seems to work.